# Android - Appium click event is not working

Tags: appium-android

I am new to appium, Wrote sample program to open app and click event for icon

Test case is passed -> Splash screen is opened , but event is not fired.Sometime its working and most of the time it wont

**Code Snippet:**

```
WebElement phoneSignIn = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("com.xyz.xyz:id/primaryGoogleLoginButton"))));

Assert.assertTrue(phoneSignIn != null && phoneSignIn.isDisplayed(), "Phone SignIn Button is not displayed");

phoneSignIn.click();
```

**Appium server log:**

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element
[HTTP] {"using":"id","value":"com.xyz.xyz:id/primaryGoogleLoginButton"}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","com.xyz.xyz:id/primaryGoogleLoginButton","388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1/element] with body: {"strategy":"id","selector":"com.xyz.xyz:id/primaryGoogleLoginButton","context":"","multiple":false}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1","value":{"ELEMENT":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510"}}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510","ELEMENT":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element 200 628 ms - 137
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/displayed
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Calling AppiumDriver.elementDisplayed() with args: ["6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510","388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851"]
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/attribute/displayed' to command name 'getAttribute'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/attribute/displayed] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/attribute/displayed] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1","value":"true"}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Responding to client with driver.elementDisplayed() result: true
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/displayed 200 17 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/click
[HTTP] {"id":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510"}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args: ["6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510","388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851"]
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/click' to command name 'click'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/click] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/click] with body: {"element":"6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510"}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"6067d30e-befe-4413-86c9-ed95af200bc1","value":null}
[debug] [W3C (388a407b)] Responding to client with driver.click() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/388a407b-99f5-4eaf-8c9b-d6d948bb8851/element/6038c598-1fce-4613-80f2-30546c9a9510/click 200 646 ms - 14
[HTTP]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please let me know above code snippet is correct

Comment: I have uninstall appium setting and clear cache , then reinstall now its working fine